# Group of kids become smarter from crashed alien ship

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

This is a book I must've read a few years ago in school, but from what I can remember a group of 2-3 kids finds this crashed ship that makes them slightly smarter.

The kids can remember things exactly as written in their textbooks, and even later on I believe they make small nuclear reactors for their houses. There is even another person that is stuck in another alien object that gets mutated by it.
Someone suggested 'Tommyknockers' by Stephen King, but that story is not this one.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was "a few years ago?"  Was this a school-provided book, or just one you read _while_ you were in school?  How long was it?  Paperback or hardcover?  Do you remember any details of the cover art?

Comment: Sadly I do not remember the cover art. It was Paperback, and while it was in the school library, it wasn't provided, just happened to be one that caught my eye at the time. This must've been 7-8 years ago if I remember correctly.

Comment: Shares some similarities with Aquila by Andrew Norriss - two boys find a crashed spaceship, and afterwards they start doing better in school - but in Aquila, the reason for their improvement is their desire to find out more about the spaceship, causing them to be more motivated, rather than an effect of the ship itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might this be book #1 of [Rho Agenda: The Second Ship](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17381835-the-second-ship)?

> And when a trio of students discovers it buried deep inside a remote canyon, they are changed forever. With a single touch, the technology the government has spent billions trying to unlock is uploaded into the minds of three teenagers—teenagers who now know the frightening truth about the Rho Project.

It's two boy-girl twins and their male friend.  Also involves a mysterious and very deadly special forces soldier who helps them.

They become pretty smart, and very tough, as I recall.  And they did create machines, I believe.

But it wasn't a YA novel.  As per a review on Amazon:

> Be warned, however, this novel is not appropriate for children. There's some pretty graphic violence and also some sexual references. But that stuff doesn't dominate the novel, fortunately.

Comment: YES!! Oh good this is it! Thank you so much, and apologies for the late reply. When I read it exactly is a bit muffled in my memory but this is it. Thank you so much once again!

Comment: @William Txs.  If it answers your question, the idea is generally to `Accept` it.  See that checkmark '✔️' under the number of votes to the left of the answer?  Clicking it says "ok, this is answers my question".  When there are multiple answers, pick the one that "helped" you most.